# Assign node value

Tags: scripting, node-editor

I am trying to assign a value to the 'Fac' input of a Mix Shader. I have tried this, but it fails (`value: invalid, expected a StructRNA type or None, not a float`):

```
mat = mat.node_tree.nodes.get('Mix Shader')
mat.inputs[0] = 0.8
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
mat = mat.node_tree.nodes.get('Mix Shader')
mat.inputs[0].default_value = 0.8
```